# Content type drop down filter types

Tags: 7, views

In the content page, there is a filter that shows the page, and other types of content.

Is there a way for me that will allow me to show only certain types of items in the content type.

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Administer views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) but to quickly achieve this I would use the `hook_form_alter`.

Do something like this, Although I would recommend you set this restriction to specific role but for this example I am going to ignore roles. Within `hook_form_alter` you do

```
if($form['#form_id] == 'node_admin_content') {
   unset($form['filter']['filters']['status']['filters']['type']['#options']['article']);
}
```

You can change the `['article']` to whatever the machine name of your content type is. use devel to find out what elements the `$form` variable contains.

Comment: Why not just create a new view or change the existing one via the UI?

Comment: Yes but instead of creating a new view installing the module I suggested on my answer will be easier and works well too.